# How to get a selected database value as a session variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to get the `id` in `users` table as a PHP session variable called `$_SESSION['id']`. But when I am printing the session variable, I have got `Undefined index` as the output.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select id, user_name, user_type from users where pw='$pass' and email='$email'") or die("Website under maintenance.");
$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$id = $jfeta['id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting already tells you that your variables in the query are not evaluated: `'".$pass."'`. Also, [please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). And please do not ask questions "my code is not working". Always include what exactly is not working with what kind of error.

Comment: @Bowdzone maybe his code is really not working - it stays home and watch TV ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you used session_start to start a session?

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

After this

```
$id = $jfeta['id'];
```

should work:

```
<?php
    $jsqla = mysql_query("select id, user_name, user_type from users where pw='".$pass."' and email='".$email."'") or die("Website under maintenance.");
    $jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

    session_start();
    $id = $jfeta['id'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
?>
```

---

your Selection could be the Problem too:

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select id, user_name, user_type from users where pw='$pass' and email='$email'") or die("Website under maintenance.");
```

could work better with this:

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select id, user_name, user_type from users where pw='".$pass."' and email='".$email."'") or die("Website under maintenance.");
```

---

The message "Undefined index" means that the one value you use isn't set.
you can prevent this by example:

```
if(isset($jfeta['id']))
{
    //do thing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

mysql is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

nevertheless... update your query.

For better overview and debugging store your sql query first in a variable:

```
$sql = "select id, user_name, user_type from users where pw='".$pass."' and email='".$email."'";
```

Now use this code:

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);


if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$id = $row["id"];

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

But again ... use mysqli or PDO - mysql is deprecated!

> Warning
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future.

Answer (score 2):

First check whether the session variable is set or not using the below code.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['id'];
} else { 
  echo "error."; 
}
```