# Login Screen - Not working

Tags: php

I've got a login screen all setup but my php code doesn't seem to work with it. Can't find the issue either as the details I'm entering are correct but it is not displaying either of the outputs. 1 - being proceed to next page. 2 - being display message saying incorrect details. Atleast thats what I think it should be doing. My code is here;

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['login'])):

 require_once('my_connect.php');
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $my_query="SELECT * from loanusers where username='$username' AND    password='$password'";
    $result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0):
    while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

    $_SESSION['userid'] = $myrow["userid"];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myrow["username"];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['usertype'] = $myrow["usertype"];
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;

    echo "<b> Hi ".$_SESSION['username']." (ID: ".$_SESSION['userid']."), You are now logged in!</b>";
    endwhile;

    //header('Location: homepage.php');

    else:
        echo "<b>Username or Password incorrect</b>";
    endif;
    mysqli_close();   

 endif; 
 require_once 'loginheader.php';

 ?>


 <html>
 <body>
 <h2>User Login</h2>
 <div id="loginp"><p>Need an Account? <a href='adduser.php'><b>Sign Up</b>  </p></a></div>


 <table>
 <form method="POST" action="homepage.php" autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..."> 
 <br><br>
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..."> 
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="loanlogin" value="Sign In"  onclick="window.location.href='homepage.php'">
 </form> 
 </table>
 <br>
 <div id="loginp"><p>Forgot your Password?<b> Click Here</b></p></a></div>
 <body>
 <html>
```

Comment: Do you have an _**Apache server**_ installed.

Comment: Yes, you need to have an Apache server

Comment: @PranavKumar apologies, Yes I am using a web server

Comment: What server and Operating System

Comment: @PranavKumar Apache/2.2.12 - Windows 7

Comment: Apache/2.2.12 is old. Get the _**LATEST**_ with the link in my answer.

Comment: Apache v2.2.12 supports only `PHP` 5.3.0. The latest Apache supports 5.3.0 above.

Comment: @Mucc019 please also show the html code

Comment: @PranavKumar html code added

Comment: Your Session method is wrong. Check this to know more: [Php Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Updated the answer. Check and let me Know. :)

Comment: Updated answer. Check the bottom line. Click the arrow on the side of this answer if it helped –

Comment: @Mucca019 This is not a solution to your problem, just an observation: please check your HTML syntax, you misplaced `</a>` tag. It should be inside the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html post action was taking me to another page bypassing the login script.

I changed the action to index.php and the login now displays an error if the details are incorrect and takes me to the take page if details are correct.

Thanks All for helping

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **onclick** Like  user nv1t   said as, there is already an `form action` referring to the same page.  **`onclick`** functions are only for `<button>` tags

To pull the value, check this [how to get a selected database value as a session variable in php - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958896/how-to-get-a-selected-database-value-as-a-session-variable-in-php)

Click the tick near the answer if this helped.

Comment: I need to pull the session variable information from my database rather than setting it in my php code. using $myrow["username"]; is this not correct?

Comment: Updated answer. Check the bottom line. Click the arrow on the side of this answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Check these two Ideas:

1. What are the values of  `$username`and `$password` before you issue them to the select statement. (i would guess they are empty, then remove the onclick)
2. is their really a username with this password in the database.

i would guess it's the onclick in your submit. You don't need this event their and it is not submitting the Form element.

> Note that your code looks vulnerable to [SQL](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) and [XSS](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/) injections, it's important to learn about security too while learning in PHP :-)